# How to nullify a global Authorize attribute for a specific action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have a global `AuthorizeAttribute` which is applied throughout my app to check authorization

I have a single controller however which shouldn't be authorized when built in debug mode (it contains my jasmine unit tests).

How do I tell Asp.Net Mvc to not use authorization for just this one controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried [AllowAnonymous] attribute

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult LogIn () {
   }
```